# Prevent encoding errors in Python

Tags: python, windows, encoding, console

I have scripts which print out messages by the logging system or sometimes print commands. On the Windows console I get error messages like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 939, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 4537:character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a general way to make all encodings in the logging system, print commands, etc. *fail-safe* (ignore errors)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your terminal/shell (cmd as your are on Windows) cannot print every Unicode character.

You can fail-safe encode your strings with the `errors` argument of the `str.encode` method. For example you can replace not supported chars with `?` by setting `errors='replace'`.

```
>>> s = u'\u2019'
>>> print s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can\'t encode character u'\u2019' in position
 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print s.encode('cp850', errors='replace')
?
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) for other options.

**Edit** If you want a general solution for the logging, you can subclass `StreamHandler`:

```
class CustomStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

    def emit(self, record):
        record = record.encode('cp850', errors='replace')
        logging.StreamHandler.emit(self, record)
```

Comment: But if I pre-encode all strings they change type (to bytes) which might change their behaviour in the interior? Also it's in the built-in codec library. I cannot change that. Can I set an option in codec?

Comment: Edited my answer with a general logging solution.

Comment: And is there a general solution so that I don't have to change code at different places (substitute handlers)? Maybe some global option for encoding errors?

Comment: If you don't use multiple loggers (by using `getLogger`) you have to set the handler once. If you use multiple handlers, you can use `setLoggerClass` with a custom class which is using the handler.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17337953/307454) seems to get the job done, quite effectively.