# Python 2.7: output utf-8 in Windows console

Tags: python, windows, utf-8

Let's say

```
s = u"test\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0623\u0643\u0628\u0631\u7206\u767A\u043E\u043B\u043E\u043B\u043E"
```

If I try to print it directly,

```
>>> print s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\u0627' in position 4: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So I change the console into UTF-8 from within Python (otherwise it won't understand my input).

```
import win32console
win32console.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)
win32console.SetConsoleCP(65001)
```

And then output the string encoded as utf-8, because Python doesn't know that chcp 65001 is UTF-8 (a known [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602)).

```
>>> print s.encode('utf-8')
testالله أكبر爆発ололоTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

As you can see, it prints successfully until it hits a newline, then it throws an IOError.

The following workaround works:

```
def safe_print(str):
    try:
        print str.encode('utf-8')
    except:
        pass
    print

>>> safe_print(s)
testالله أكبر爆発ололо
```

But there must be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I hope you don't actually call the argument `str`. Avoid shadowing builtins.

Comment: @Chris: How is one supposed to know what is a builtin and what isn’t? It’s a very natural thing to do.  How can you guarantee clean namespace behavior without requiring universal knowledge for starting?

Comment: In this case, though, it is potentially very confusing, as the `str` type does have an encode method.

Comment: @tchrist - Most programming editors with a python mode should highlight builtins in a different colour. This is the easiest way to make sure you don't accidentally use one as a variable or argument name.

Comment: @DaveP: I've never used a colorified editor in my life. I find that languages that require IDEs to program in are just too hard. A person should be able to do it on their own without a program as a crutch. Too fragile and dangerous otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist: If you never use syntax hiliting, you are making your life harder than it needs to be. It catches a lot of small problems, such as *ahem* shadowing built-ins and unclosed comments/strings. Too fragile and dangerous otherwise. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

[Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20utf8%20windows) SO for *python utf8 windows* brings as the first result the question [Getting python to print in UTF8 on Windows XP with the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7014430/95735) which describes what's the problem with printing utf8 in Windows from Python.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it on windows, but [here](http://dumpz.org/47667/) you can get small initialization script for both win/linux to setup output encoding properly, including logging interface, etc. The module also makes output colored (including update of 'logging' interface)? but you can cut it off unnecessary functionality easily :-).

How to invoke non-colored variant:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setupcon import setup_console
setup_console('utf-8', False)
```

and colored variant:

```
import setupcon
setupcon.setup_console()
import logging
#...
if setupcon.ansi:
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(setupcon.ColoredHandler())
```

If the solution works for you, you can either read the documentation here: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/117236/, in Russian, or I/somebody can translate it for you on demand :-).