# dictionary data extraction issue

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, extract

top_100 is a mongodb collection:

the following code:

```
x=[]
thread=[]
for doc in top_100.find():
    x.append(doc['_id'])




db = Connection().test

top_100 = db.top_100_thread

thread = [a["thread"] for a in x]

for doc in thread:
    print doc
```

gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chatterjees\workspace\de.vogella.python.first\src\top_100_thread.py",        line 21, in <module>
    print doc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u03b9' in position 10:      character maps to <undefined>
```

what's going on?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I would write your first for-loop as a list comprehension `x = [doc['_id'] for doc in top_100.find()]`

Comment: @Daan Timmer What is a good source to learn these nuances of Python?

Comment: Well, you already used a list comprehension on your `thread = [...]` line. So you either already know how it works or you are good at copy-pasting. Best way that I've learned to find these nuances is by writing code. Then iterating over it and looking for for-loops. If found, see if I can minimalize/shorten it by writing pythonic code. Didn't really use a source/book/website for it. [this is however a really nice source](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) of some smart-python-usage.

Comment: thanks, I understood that part of the code but missed that its part of list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your document contains some unicode data.
You need to correctly output unicode data
instead of directly printing it.
see:
[python 3.0, how to make print() output unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507123/python-3-0-how-to-make-print-output-unicode)