# print unicode characters in terminal with python 3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, terminal

I'm currently writing a 2-player chess game for the terminal and I'd like to be able to print the actual unicode characters for the pieces (for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)#Unicode). How would one go about printing actual unicode representations in python 3 instead of escape characters? does the charset of the terminal need to be changed (I primarily use windows and linux), and can that be done by a system call in the program itself?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507123/python-3-0-how-to-make-print-output-unicode

Comment: Having anything else than line printing of ascii and making it work in both Windows terminal and Linux terminals needs a library. UniCurses is a Python library that wraps curses/PDCurses. I haven't used it, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30505612/788700

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err... print them...

```
3>> print('♔♕♖')
♔♕♖
```

Windows will probably need `chcp 65001` before running the script.

Comment: After executing `chcp 65001` I get this error when trying to run Python: "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001"

Comment: That would be a problem with that particular Python installation then.

Comment: it looks like this is going to be a linux-only program. Windows terminal seems to be very tetchy with nonasci, I can't even echo those characters in the terminal after I change to 65001, it just exits. Thanks for your input

Comment: Make sure to use the right encoding on your linux console... Check this question for more info [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306153/how-to-get-terminals-character-encoding)

Comment: Support for cp65001 was added in Python3.3, but it still doesn't work right.

Comment: I'm on W7 terminal and ipython, can't get emoji to display...missing my *unix environment.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 doesn't need anything extra for that, just use `print()`.

```
>>> print('القاموس العربي')
القاموس العربي
```