# Pass unicode character to from os.walk to print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am trying to create a simple file indexing utility in Python 3.4. The goal is to enable quick searching for a filename using an index.

To do this I have used the os.walk function, but I get a UnicodeEncodeError when trying to print the name of a directory. I looked at other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507123/python-3-0-how-to-make-print-output-unicode) but they don't seem to describe the same error (UnicodeEncodeError).

My code is:

```
def index_files(path_to_index):
    indexed_files = []

    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_to_index):
        # print path to all subdirectories first.
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

        # print path to all filenames.
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            print("Found " + full_path)
            indexed_files.append(full_path)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[OMITTED LOCAL PATH]indexer.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "[OMITTED LOCAL PATH]indexer.py", line 37, in main
    indexed_files = index_files(path_to_index)
  File "[OMITTED LOCAL PATH]indexer.py", line 16, in index_files
    print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 31-34: character maps to <undefined>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: At issue here is your console, it is configured to only handle the [CP 850 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (MS-DOS western alphabet). You'll need to reconfigure your console.