# How can I resolve UnicodeEncodeError calling response.json from a requests.post to validator.w3.org?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.4

I wanted to be able to validate some html produced from a template rendering function in my Python code.

I went to the [Github page for validator.w3.org](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service%3A-Input%3A-POST-body) to consult the API.

Following my interpretation of what I read, I tried the following code:

```
import requests
import urllib    

index_html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  '\
    '<meta charset="UTF-8">\n  '\
    '<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  \n</body>\n</html>\n'
FRAGMENT = ''
query = {}
QUERY = 3
tokens = ['https', 'validator.w3.org', 'nu/', query, FRAGMENT]
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
query = {'out': 'json'}
query = urllib.parse.urlencode(query)
tokens[QUERY] = query
url = urllib.parse.urlunsplit(tokens)
kwargs = dict(
    headers=headers,
    data=index_html,
)
response = requests.post(url, **kwargs)
```

`response.json()` returns:

> *** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

`response.content` is this:

> b'{"messages":[{"type":"info","message":"The Content-Type was \xe2\x80\x9ctext/html\xe2\x80\x9d. Using the HTML parser."},{"type":"info","message":"Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support."},{"type":"error","lastLine":5,"lastColumn":17,"firstColumn":10,"message":"Element \xe2\x80\x9ctitle\xe2\x80\x9d must not be empty.","extract":"\n  \n

The `type(response.content)` is `<class 'bytes'>`.
I know that `json.loads` requires a string so I postulated that the `response.json` was throwing an exception because the content was in bytes that failed to decode into a string:

```
import json
json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Indeed, same exception:

> *** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

My knowledge has run out and has left me stuck wondering what part of this code to change in order to get the JSON from the `requests.post` `response`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This seems like an issue when using Python 2.x rather than Python 3.x; can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Doh! Your comment made me recall I had been fiddling with Python versions in my virtualenv. I just tried my code in python3.4 and achieved the expected results. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶d̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶3̶.̶x̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶2̶.̶x̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶e̶c̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶3̶.̶x̶!̶

*See update below.*

Thank you.

`{'messages': [{'message': 'The Content-Type was “text/html”. Using the HTML parser.',
   'type': 'info'},
  {'message': 'Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.',
   'type': 'info'},
  {'extract': '\n  <title></title>\n</hea',
   'firstColumn': 10,
   'hiliteLength': 8,
   'hiliteStart': 10,
   'lastColumn': 17,
   'lastLine': 5,
   'message': 'Element “title” must not be empty.',
   'type': 'error'}]}`

**Update**:

There is more to this story. I was, in fact, using Python3. I just omitted the part about using py.test and the --pdb option.

How do I know I was using Python3?

Ouput from `python3 test_mytest.py` where inside test_mytest.py is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(pytest.main('-s --pdb'))
```

is this:

> platform linux -- **Python 3.4.3**, pytest-2.8.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1

I was still getting encoding errors after dropping into the pdb. I found the solution in [the answer by @daveagp in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507123/python-3-0-how-to-make-print-output-unicode)

He has written [a page](https://daveagp.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/what-a-character/) on his ordeal with this problem. Thank you @daveagp.

Once I executed `export PYTHONIOENCODING='utf_8'` I no longer had any encoding errors.

I was mistaken about my mistake!