# Special characters decoding and printing problem

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I want to parse text file. 

Lines in file look like this:

```
#all.kdadmin.filter.showAllEntries;-alle anzeigen-;-show all-;-pokaż wszystko-;-mostrar todo-; –ყველას გამოჩენა–
```

After:

```
step_0 = my_string.split(';')
print(step_0)
```

i have error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u017c' in position 67: ordinal not in range(128)
```

All founded answer all old i don't understood it realy.

 Can someone write me some peace of code how can i displey this lines in console or write in to other file?

Comment: Your terminal seems to be configured to handle ASCII characters only. Change this to UTF-8 or switch to a more powerful terminal. It might also be that the terminal *does* support UTF-8, but Python somehow doesn't realise this; in that case try exporting the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"` before launching Python.

Comment: If you're on Windows, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507123) might help, despite its age.

Comment: yes, i'm working in PowerShell, but this simple code return the same error:
    `new_days = open('new_path.txt' ,'w')
new_days.write(my_string)
new_days.close()`
can it still be a problem with a shell?

Comment: When you open a file for writing, you can specify the output encoding, ie. `open('new_path.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')`. If you omit the `encoding=` parameter, the default is the same codec that is used for printing to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks @lenz for information about problem on Windows and for help with `encoding='utf8'`  It's working now.