# UnicodeEncodeError when redirecting stdout

Tags: python, unicode

I'm having a problem regarding Unicode in Python. I can print the output fine in a regular terminal, but if I redirect `stdout` elsewhere (or capture it with the `subprocess` module), I get a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
$ cat example.py 
print u'Example: \u00F1'
$ python example.py 
Example: ñ
$ python example.py > /dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 1, in <module>
    print u'Example: \u00F1'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python is essentially the same question, the answers solved the problem I was having (hopefully)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pipes that don't lead to the terminal don't have an encoding, therefore you'll need to check [`sys.stdout.isatty()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.isatty) and encode if needed.

Comment: Or (even better) just always encode.

Comment: More info on how to define encoding: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: No, PEP 263 is about specifying *source* encoding, and has nothing to do with output encodings.

Comment: Is there an easy way to "just always encode"?

Comment: @eric, `print mystring.encode(encoding, 'ignore')`

Comment: @eric.frederich Alternatively use this at the start of your script: `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("UTF-8")(sys.stdout)`, after importing `codecs` and `sys` of course.