# Python script encoding trouble when run in CRON job

Tags: python, utf-8, cron

As many hopefully can relate, this encoding problem is driving me *mental*. I would really appreciate some light on this!

End goal is to be able to run the same script.py from both terminal and cron, and from cron with `> stdout.txt`. And needless to say, I'm having serious encoding troubles.

My script.py runs fine from terminal thus: `python script.py`

It throws an error, however, when run from terminal thus: `python script.py > stdout.txt`

It throws same error when run in cron, either way.

I have a python script, entered in `crontab -e` as root.

This is my script.py header:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This is my cron entry:

```
* * * * * python /home/ubuntu/parrot/script.py > /home/ubuntu/parrot/stdout.txt
```

This is my stdout.txt (the relevant part):

```
Unexpected error!  (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>, UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'blabla some weird text n\xc3\xa5r end', 54, 55, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

This is my env from terminal (the relevant part):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This is my env from cron (the relevant part):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This is the (first) line in script.py throwing the error:

```
print 'Posting @%s: %s' % (statusObj.user.screen_name.encode('ascii', 'replace'), statusObj.text.encode('utf-8', 'replace'))
```

Edit:
`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `ascii`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `sys.getdefaultencoding()` return?

Comment: why do i have a feeling that's bad?..

Comment: If this isn't the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224130/unicodeencodeerror-when-redirecting-stdout it is close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError only when running as a cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932406/unicodeencodeerror-only-when-running-as-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the `statusObj` you should check the relevant code where data is being parsed into the object and try to get the input as *clean* as possible.

You want to make sure your string is decoded to unicode before you try to encode it.

If not you can try:

```
# try to get the string into unicode
screen_name = unicode(statusObj.user.screen_name) 
post = unicode(statusObj.text) # probably an error here?
output_str = u"Posting @{name}: {post}".format(name=screen_name, post=post)
print output_str.encode("utf8", "replace") # encode the unicode string on
```

Comment: but my code already works from CLI. so it must be something with the encoding environment of cron?? i will try tho. thank you!

Comment: i just added sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
to the top and deleted the .encode'ings altogether. problem solved! thanks a lot all! =)