# python unichr problem

Tags: python, unicode, ubuntu

I've got some problem with `unichr()` on my server. Please see below:

On my server (Ubuntu 9.04):

```
>>> print unichr(255)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On my desktop (Ubuntu 9.10):

```
>>> print unichr(255)
ÿ
```

I'm fairly new to python so I don't know how to solve this. Anyone care to help? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389410/python-string-decoding-issue

Answer (score 6):

When using the "`print`" keyword, you'll be writing to the `sys.stdout` output stream. `sys.stdout` can usually only display Unicode strings if the characters can be converted to ascii using `str(message)`.

You'll need to encode to your OS's terminal encoding when printing to be able to do this.

The `locale` module can sometimes detect the encoding of the output console:

```
import locale
print unichr(0xff).encode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1], 'replace')
```

but it's usually better to just specify the encoding yourself, as python often gets it wrong:

```
print unichr(0xff).encode('latin-1', 'replace')
```

UTF-8 or latin-1 I think is often used in many modern linux distros.

If you know the encoding of your console, the lines below will encode Unicode strings automatically when you use "`print`":

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(ENCODING)(sys.stdout)
```

If the encoding is ascii or something similar, you may need to change the console encoding of your OS to be able to display that character.

See also: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Answer (score 2):

The terminal settings on your server are different, probably set to 7-bit US ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really `unichr()` related. Problem is with locale setting in your server environment, as it's probably set to something like `en_US` and it's not unicode aware.

Comment: That's probably it since I get the same result when I'm executing the code trough a .py-file. Do you know what I need to do to change this?

Comment: try $ export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an explicit [encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) when printing unicode strings where OS settings are not uniform.

> `unicode.encode([encoding[, errors]])`
>
> Return an encoded version of the string. Default encoding is the current default string encoding. errors may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The default for errors is 'strict', meaning that encoding errors raise a UnicodeError. Other possible values are 'ignore', 'replace', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace' and any other name registered via codecs.register_error(), see section Codec Base Classes. For a list of possible encodings, see section Standard Encodings.

For example,

```
>>> print unichr(0xff).encode('iso8859-1')
����??
>>>
```