# How to get a single unicode character from its integer representation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I did not want to post this question but tried almost all the things, nothing seems to work. On python 2.7

```
ord(unicode('₹', "utf-8"))
```

This produces `8377` as the output. How do I get `'₹'` from `8377`?

`unichr(8377)` and `chr(8377)` do not work as they throw `ordinal not in range(128)` exception.
I tried other things as well but I think I am headed in a wrong direction.

Comment: If you're getting this error then it means your default encoding is set to 'ascii', you could do: `print unichr(8377).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Which terminal do you use?

Comment: pycharm's pydevconsole. `print unichr(8377)` works fine but if you do `unichr(8377)` it does not give `'₹'` as output. Its `u'\u20b9'`

Comment: That's fine, `u'\u20b9'` is repr version of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) :

```
>>> unichr(8377)
u'\u20b9'
```

This should work on any python 2.7 on any system.

It does exactly what you asked : it returns a single unicode character from its integer representation. This unicode character isn't displayed as `₹`, though. Instead, a repr version is returned, which can be displayed with ascii characters.

Depending on your terminal, `print` will either display the character correctly :

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> unichr(8377)
u'\u20b9'
>>> print unichr(8377)
₹
```

or throw an error (powershell on Windows) :

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (
Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print unichr(8377)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in en
code
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20b9' in position
 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

## Possible solution

Your terminal needs to accept unicode characters.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584296/6419007) might help you :

```
import locale
print unichr(8377).encode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1], 'replace')
```

Depending on your encoding, the character might be displayed correctly or as a `?`.

This character substitution is called ["tofu"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296505/where-is-tofu-for-font-fallback-box-glyph-coming-from) or ["mojibake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), and it isn't a Python problem. It's related to the underlying terminal (e.g. Powershell).

[Those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105022/unicode-in-powershell-with-python-alternative-shells-in-windows) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001) might help you.

Comment: "`unichr(8377)` and `chr(8377)` do not work" - and still doesn't work after `import unicodedata`, either (for me at least).

Comment: It's expected for `chr(8377)` not to work with Python 2. `unichr` should work, at least it does on all the systems I tried it on (Win, Linux, Mac Os) with Python 2.7. Which version do you use, on which system?

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work, on 2.7.9 in 8.1's PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce. It outputs '?' in my PowerShell, without throwing any error. just using `print unichr(8377)` does produce an error, though.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's powershell's problem, not Python's. If powershell cannot display the Indian rupee sign, there's nothing Python can do about it when inside Powershell.

Comment: To the downvoters : it's not my fault if Powershell sucks.

Comment: When you tell someone to do `print(*lst)` and they tell you it's a syntax error, do you tell them it's not your fault if Python 2 sucks?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: There's a difference, though. It's very possible to achieve the desired output with Python2, albeit with a different syntax : `for l in lst:
    print l,`