# Django, python non-ascii character on openshift

Tags: python, django, openshift, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I have a django 1.5, python 2.7 app in openshift and i'm getting a DjangoUnicodeDecodeError with non-ascii characters, like ç,á,ã..

I've spent some hours trying to fix this (i'm begginer in python, django and openshift)

**It is not happening locally, just in the openshift cloud server.**

Is there any way to fix this via ssh? Or any other..

Here is the printstack:

```
Request Method: POST

Request URL: ----

Django Version: 1.5

Exception Type: DjangoUnicodeDecodeError

Exception Value:
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.proxy object at 0x7f10ccfde9d0> ()
Exception Location: /var/lib/openshift/.../python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 115

Python Executable: /var/lib/openshift/.../python//virtenv/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.5

Python Path:...
```

Thanks,

Roberto.

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389410/python-string-decoding-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues recently on my machine, I solved by using unicode literals + smart_text:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text


safeText = smart_text('this is my tetxt : %s' % someVaribleHoldingTextData)
```

alternatively you may need to decode data read from a file to a specific charset:

```
theFile = open(path, 'r')
safeData = theFile.read().decode('utf-8')
```

encoding is an hard topic… you have to try, and try again :P

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna try it now and come back soon.. thanks

Comment: cool! I'm happy you fixed the problem so fast, I lost a whole day to fix the problem by myself some days ago :D

Comment: I saw now that the same error occurs with e-mails sending.. do you know if is there another aproach for this case?

Comment: smart_text calls force_text internally… you could inspect django sources :)

Comment: django 1.4.1 don't have smart_text in django.utils.encoding yet.