# How to left align a UTF-8 encoded string in python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, format

I'm trying to left align an UTF-8 encoded string with `string.ljust`. This exception is raised: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. For example,

```
s = u"你好"    // a Chinese string
stdout.write(s.encode("UTF-8").ljust(20))
```

Am I on the right track? Or I should use other approach to format?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you post the exact code and the exact error you received?  Because your code works without throwing an error on both a `cp437` and `utf-8` terminal.  In any case you should justify the Unicode string before sending it to the terminal.  Note the difference because the UTF-8-encoded Chinese has length 6 when encoded instead of length 2:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(s.encode('utf-8').ljust(20) + "hello")
你好              hello
>>> sys.stdout.write(s.ljust(20).encode('utf-8') + "hello")
你好                  hello
```

Note also that Chinese characters are wider than the other characters in typical fixed-width fonts so things may still not line up as you like if mixing languages (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4632373/235698) for a solution):

```
>>> sys.stdout.write("12".ljust(20) + "hello")
12                  hello
```

Normally you can skip explicit encoding to `stdout`.  Python implicitly encodes Unicode strings to the terminal in the terminal's encoding (see `sys.stdout.encoding`):

```
sys.stdout.write(s.ljust(20))
```

Another option is using `print`:

```
print "%20s" % s   # old-style
```

or:

```
print '{:20}'.format(s)  # new-style
```