# How to pad and align unicode strings with special characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode, string-formatting

Python makes it easy to pad and align ascii strings, like so:

```
>>> print "%20s and stuff" % ("test")
                test and stuff
>>> print "{:>20} and stuff".format("test")
                test and stuff
```

But how can I properly pad and align unicode strings containing special characters? I've tried several methods, but none of them seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

def manual(data):
    for s in data:
        size = len(s)
        print ' ' * (20 - size) + s + " stuff"

def with_format(data):
    for s in data:
        print " {:>20} stuff".format(s) 

def with_oldstyle(data):   
    for s in data:
        print "%20s stuff" % (s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ("xTest1x", "ツTestツ", "♠️ Test ♠️", "~Test2~")
    data_utf8 = map(lambda s: s.decode("utf8"), data)

    print "with_format"
    with_format(data)
    print "with_oldstyle"
    with_oldstyle(data)
    print "with_oldstyle utf8"
    with_oldstyle(data_utf8)
    print "manual:"
    manual(data)
    print "manual utf8:"
    manual(data_utf8)
```

This gives varied output:

```
with_format
              xTest1x stuff
           ツTestツ stuff
   ♠️ Test ♠️ stuff
              ~Test2~ stuff
with_oldstyle
             xTest1x stuff
          ツTestツ stuff
  ♠️ Test ♠️ stuff
             ~Test2~ stuff
with_oldstyle utf8
             xTest1x stuff
              ツTestツ stuff
          ♠️ Test ♠️ stuff
             ~Test2~ stuff
manual:
             xTest1x stuff
          ツTestツ stuff
  ♠️ Test ♠️ stuff
             ~Test2~ stuff
manual utf8:
             xTest1x stuff
              ツTestツ stuff
          ♠️ Test ♠️ stuff
             ~Test2~ stuff
```

This is using Python 2.7.

Comment: I think `data_utf8` better be renamed to `data_unicode` as it contains the latter.

Comment: it is maybe related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622357/how-to-control-padding-of-unicode-string-containing-east-asia-characters

Comment: You may be interested in the Unicode Standard's concept of a ["grapheme cluster"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries), which roughly corresponds to the characters perceived by a user reading a piece of text, and third-party modules for computing grapheme clusters, like [`uniseg.graphemecluster`](http://uniseg-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphemecluster.html). You might want to do some sort of additional handling for zero-width characters, though, and of course for non-monospaced fonts, padding would work very differently.

Comment: You generally can't because that text might be rendered with different fonts, and you don't know which width every character will have. Eg. on my box `'ツ'` is slightly wider than `'a'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [wcwidth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wcwidth) module available via pip.

test.py:

```
import wcwidth
def manual_wcwidth(data):
    for s in data:
        size = wcwidth.wcswidth(s)
        print ' ' * (20 - size) + s + " stuff"
data = (u"xTest1x", u"ツTestツ", u"♠️ Test ♠️", u"~Test2~")
manual_wcwidth(data)
```

In the linux console this script yields for me perfectly aligned lines:

[image: console screenshot]

However when I run the script in PyCharm the line with kana is still shifted one character left, so this seems also font and renderer dependent:

[image: pycharm screenshot]

Comment: This works well for our purposes (we are using OS X Terminal to display the text). Thanks for the tip!

We should probably note that this requires "pip install wcwidth"

Comment: Japanese and Chinese characters are full width characters and are slightly wider than other characters in most (all?) fonts.  About 3 full width characters equals 4 regular characters, so only having two in the string results in a slightly off alignment due to rounding.