# Trying to use output.write with UTF-8 str and get's an error (python 3.x)

Tags: python, string, utf-8, output

I'm using the following code to print (to file) UTF-8 str :

```
output.write(currentWord.m_wordHeb)
```

tried also :

```
output.write(currentWord.m_wordHeb.encode('utf-8')
```

and also added :

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
```

keeps getting errors ... 
usually this one :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is the type and value of `currentWord.m_wordHeb`? Please show the output of `print(type(currentWord.m_wordHeb))` and `print(currentWord.m_wordHeb)`

Comment: i get the following error for both print lines :     
'TypeError: must be str, not bytes'     
I build the string using several methods, which returns something like : u'א' (which is Hebrew char)  
and building as : 'string += method()'  
So i can't understand why it is bytes and not str.

Comment: I highly doubt that `print(type(...bla...))` gives you the error message `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` unless you have done something incredibly nasty such as changing the definition of `print`. But if you can show a complete, self-contained piece of code that is runnable and gives this error, I'd be interested to see it. Because when I run your code (after guessing the missing parts) I do 
*not* get that error.

Comment: well, that was the error, whenever i added 'wb' to the open command of the file that worked out, but the characters are wrong (not hebrew text but garbage)

Comment: Note that the line "sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)" should be replaced with "sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.detach())" to work well with python 3.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4374457/1825043.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved, the file i opened for writing wasn't opened as it should for utf-8.
So when i changed the 'open command' to the following :

```
codecs.open("C:\\NLP\\output.txt", "w", "utf-8" )
```

everything seems to work out.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can only encode a string. If you currently have bytes instead, it's because your method is returning them as so. If you read the bytes from a file, for example, you should decode them into a string as soon as possible. Only then can you encode them to utf-8.

Comment: How can i return the Hebrew characters as string and not as bytes ?

Comment: @SagiLow in my python3 interpreter, if I enter 'א', it actually returns a string. If you have bytes (which you will, if you're reading the file as binary), you just need to do bytes.decode('utf-8') (or whatever encoding you're using)

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the way i read the file, since i'm trying to print a simple string variable which was created by the methods i mentioned above.

Comment: @SagiLow doing a simple `'א'.encode('utf-8')` on the python3 shell fails?

Comment: The string is built just fine, the problem is with the "Writer".
If i use 'print(currentWord.m_wordHeb)' that works just fine, but if i use outputFile.write((currentWord.m_wordHeb)) i get an error !

Comment: @SagiLow It would be worthwhile to just provide a small snippet that we can **run** in your question, and reproduces your problem. What is `output`/`outputFile`? A file, a stream? Are you just writing to `stdout`? If so, isn't `print` sufficient?

Comment: I open the output file : inline 'code' (outputFile = open('C:\\X\\output.txt' ,'w')) than i create the str as i specified .. and tries to write back to the file : [code] outputFile.write((currentWord.m_wordHeb))[/code]