# Python 3 throws UnicodeEncodeError with environment variable LANG=C

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, locale

I have the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print('☺')
```

When I run it on my Debian system, it produces the following output, as expected:

```
$ ./test.py 
☺
$
```

However, when I change locale to "C", by setting the `LANG` environment variable, the script throws a `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
$ LANG=C ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('\u263a')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u263a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
$
```

This problem prevents this script from being executed in minimal environments, such as during boot or in embedded systems. Also, I suspect that many existing Python programs can be broken by executing them with `LANG=C`. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095382/python-3-4-causes-unicodeencodeerror-on-apache2-server-mac-but-works-fine-in-c) on Stackoverflow of a program that presumably broke because it's executed in the "C"-locale.

Is this a bug in Python? What's the best way to prevent this?

Comment: "Is this a bug in Python?" — You're telling Python to print WHITE SMILING FACE in a locale that doesn't have it.  I don't think that's Python's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Python 3 uses the locale settings to deduce the output character encoding; that is, Python will use the locale that would be displayed for `LC_CTYPE` when you execute the locale command:

```
% locale 
...
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

If you force `LC_CTYPE` to `C`, then Python will assume that ASCII should be used as the output encoding. And ASCII doesn't have a mapping for `U+263A`.

If you want Python to know how to encode Unicode properly, set the `LC_CTYPE` to an appropriate value, or write binary to fd 1.

Comment: Does this mean that, in order to make a script portable, I should always test what the current locale setting is before I try to print Unicode strings?

Comment: @hedgie You can't make a truly portable script that prints non-ASCII characters. There are too many terminals that don't support it.