# Transmitting a pickled object output between python scripts through a subprocess.communicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have two python scripts:object_generator.py which pickles a given object and prints it. Another script object_consumer.py picks the output of the first script through a subprocess.communicate and tries to unpickle it using pickle.loads. I am having trouble making this simple scenario work. This is my code:

## object_generator.py

```
import pickle
import base64

o = {'first':1,'second':2,'third':3,'ls':[1,2,3]}
d = pickle.dumps(o)
print(d)

#Various Approaches I had tried, none of which worked. Ignore this part.
#s = base64.b64decode(d)
#encoded_str = str(d).encode('ascii')
#print('encoded str is :')
#print(encoded_str)
#decoded_str = encoded_str.decode('ascii')
#print('decoded str is :')
#print(decoded_str)
#unpickled_obj = pickle.loads(bytes(decoded_str))
#print(unpickled_obj)
#print(type(d))
#print(codecs.decode(d))
```

## object_consumer.py

```
import pickle
import subprocess
import os

dr = '"' + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\object_generator.py"'

cmd = 'python -u ' + dr

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()

# 'out' at this point is something like this : 
# b"b'\\x80\\x03}q\......x05K\\x03u.'\r\n"
# DO SOMETHING WITH outs to get back the bytes which can then be 
# unpickled using pickle.loads

obj = pickle.loads(outs)
print(obj)
```

Clearly, I need to strip off the trailing \r\n which is easy but what should be done next?

Comment: Does your effort aim at having the scenario work using th very given `subprocess` module method `.communicate()`, or are you open to implement a python process-to-process communication solution, be it using a `subprocess` or other means?

Comment: I tried subprocess.check_ouput and then moved to communicate when that didnt work but I have no restriction to use communicate. I would appreciate any alternate method along with a explanation of what is wrong in this.

Comment: Always good to separate an issue of the process-to-process communication from the issues of payload representation/coding/serialisation/encapsulation/framing. For the former, may be usefull to get an overview on fast, scale-able process-to-process messaging **ZeroMQ** ( with many ports, incl. python ) where you get all the powers under your control, so being able to fit the communication archetypes into your distributed parallel processing Project needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues going on here. First, you're printing a `bytes` object in `object_generator.py`. In Python 3.x, that's going to result in `str(obj)` being called, which means  `b'yourbyteshere'` gets printed. You don't want the leading `b'` or trailing `'`. To fix that, you need to encode the `bytes` object as a string. `pickle` uses the `'latin-1'` encoding, so we can use that to decode the `bytes` object to a `str`. The other issue is that the encoding Windows uses by default for `sys.stdout` doesn't actually support printing decoded `pickle` strings. So, we need to change the default encoding for `sys.stdout`* to `'latin-1'`, so the string will make it to the parent process with the correct encoding.

```
import pickle
import base64
import codecs

o = {'first':1,'second':2,'third':3,'ls':[1,2,3]}
d = pickle.dumps(o)
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding='latin-1')
print(d.decode('latin-1'), end='', flush=True)  # end='' will remove that extra \r\n
```

Make those changes, and it should work fine.

**Edit:**

Another option would be to set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `'latin-1'` from the parent process:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'latin-1'
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'async2.py'] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env=env)
```

<sub>* See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4374455/2073595) for more info on changing the `sys.stdout` encoding in Python 3. Both approaches I show here are mentioned there.</sub>

Comment: It worked. I see you retracted your answer and re-posted with the fix. Appreciate your patience and the trouble taken.

Comment: @rusticbit Yes, my original answer worked fine on Linux, but didn't work on Windows. I forgot about the difference in the default encoding `sys.stdout` uses on Windows.

Comment: @rusticbit I've updated my answer to use the `io` module instead of `codecs`, since the `io` module [should generally be preferred over the `codecs` module](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-December/593460.html). I also added a way to solve the problem from the parent script.

Answer (score 1):

i don't suggest you using pickle between your main file and an unknow external one since it require the original classes to be live and it's also slow.

I used marshall module, hope this will save you time: https://github.com/jstar88/pyCommunicator