# python print function in windows converts \n to \r\n. How to prevent that?

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.4

I have a python process(say abc.py) which prints a latin1 encoded pickle output which contains `\n`

This is the code which generates the binary pickle output

```
byte_array = pickle.dumps(result)    

#Windows uses utf-8 encoding by default
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/4374457/2073595
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/26220050/1873328
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding='latin-1')
print(byte_array.decode('latin-1'), end='', flush=True)
```

The output is in the following format

```
...00USR_RDER_TYPEq\x06X\n\x00\x00\x00VERSION_.....
```

Note that this binary string contains \n

I have another sublime plugin which uses suprocess.Popen to run the above script and fetch the pickled output using communicate

```
db_process =  subprocess.Popen('python -u abc.py',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,cwd=scripts_folder,shell=True,universal_newlines=False)
try:      
  output, errs = db_process.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
  db_process.kill()
  output, errs = db_process.communicate()

#unpickle the output
obj = pickle.loads(output)
```

My problem is that in the variable `output`, `\n` is changed to `\r\n`, i.e the above pickle output will be received as

```
...00USR_RDER_TYPEq\x06X\r\n\x00\x00\x00VERSION_....
```

This leads to problems in un-pickling. I cannot replace the occurences as it is a binary string. How do I solve this problem?

PS: I am using **python 3.4**

Comment: are you reading it from a file at some point ?

Comment: no. It is basically a inter process communication using pipe.

Comment: What is the reason for the shell=True?

Comment: Setting universl_newlines=True throws this error : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2468: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: if shell is not set to true, it displays an explicit command window as shown here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/US6Ad.png

Answer (score 2):

I do **NOT** know how to remove the conversion from `\n` to `\r\n`.

But you can encode and decode it so that there are no spaces or they do not matter.

```
import base64
byte_array = pickle.dumps(result)
print(base64.b64encode(byte_array))
```

and then you need to revert the encoding.

```
import base64
obj = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(output))
```