# read tweets extracted with python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, twitter, utf-8, tweepy

I am trying to read tweets in excel. Tweets have been retrieved with `python` (and `tweepy`) then saved in a `csv` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
writer= csv.writer(open(r"C:\path\twitter_"+date+".csv", "w"), lineterminator='\n', delimiter =';')
writer.writerow(["username", "nb_followers", "tweet_text"])

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="dengue+OR+%23dengue", lang="en", since=date, until=end_date).items():
    username=tweet.user.screen_name
    nb_followers=tweet.user.followers_count
    tweet_text=tweet.text.encode('utf-8')  

    writer.writerow([username, nb_followers, tweet_text])
```

Due to the utf-8 encoding, I have problems reading them in a text editor or excel.
For example this tweet:

[image]

gives this in excel:

```
b"\xe2\x80\x9c@ThislsWow: I want to do this \xf0\x9f\x98\x8d http://t.co/rGfv9e70Tj\xe2\x80\x9d pu\xc3\xb1eta you're going to get bitten by the mosquito and get dengue"
```

How to get the original characters? How to remove the b at the beginning, useful only in a python program?

---

**EDIT :**

As per Alastair McCormack's comment: 
I removed the encoding of my field and added it in the writer:

```
writer= csv.writer(open(r"C:\path\twitter_"+date+".csv", "w", encoding="UTF-8"), lineterminator='\n', delimiter =';')
tweet_text=tweet.text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")
```

Now I have the following error:

```
tweet: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_influence.py", line 88, in <module>
    print("tweet:", tweet_text)
  File "C:\Users\rlalande\Envs\tweepy\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 137: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

**EDIT2 :**

I am now using the following:

```
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

(seen in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374457/1875861)

There is no more error but it doesn't output the correct characters.

For example this tweet:
[image]
gives this output in excel:

```
Malay Mail Online  Alarming rise in dengue casesMalay Mail Onlineâ€œThe ministry started a campaign for constructionâ€¦ http://t.co/MuLFlMwkY0
```

Before, with direct encoding of the field, I had:

```
b'Malay Mail Online\n\nAlarming rise in dengue casesMalay Mail Online\xe2\x80\x9cThe ministry started a campaign for construction\xe2\x80\xa6 http://t.co/MuLFlMwkY0'
```

The result is different but not really better... Why is the quote character not outputted correctly? In one case it outputs â€¦ and in the other case \xe2\x80\xa6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the CSV writer expects all input to be Unicode strings. You're getting the __repr__() of a byte string.

Set the encoding of your output file by replacing the first line with:

```
writer= csv.writer(open(r"C:\path\twitter_"+date+".csv", "w", encoding="UTF-8"), lineterminator='\n', delimiter =';')
```

This means that any Unicode strings written to the file will be translated automagically. Then remove the explicit `encode()`:

```
tweet_text=tweet.text
```

**Edit:**

Excel needs to be coerced into reading UTF-8 files if you don't use the import function. The easiest way to do this is to add UTF-8 BOM signature to the start of the file.

Python provides a shortcut if you use the `utf_8_sig` encoding. E.g.

```
writer= csv.writer(open(r"C:\path\twitter_"+date+".csv", "w", encoding="utf_8_sig"), lineterminator='\n', delimiter =';')
```

You can also check your file in a decent UTF-8 editor like Notepad++ or Atom.

Comment: Where and what's the error? Can you point to the line that is throwing the error?

Comment: Also, which version of Python 3.x are you using? I see that early 3.x versions didn't support Unicode in CSV in the same way as 2.x does.

Comment: I have python 3.4.3. I have edited my initial post to provide more information about the error.

Comment: Remove the print statement (as per original line listing) and it'll work. To ensure your stdout works correctly, set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in your environment or see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3

Comment: @rom I've just noticed you're on Windows. Windows Console encoding is brokem. Make sure to run your scripts within an IDE (IDLE, Eclipse or PyCharm), or iPython, or follow: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console. You'll probably find it easier just to always write UTF-8 output to a file instead.

Comment: I just tried win unicode console, it doesn't work for me. However, using the post you linked is interesting as it gives a slightly different result. But the problem is still not solved. See my original post...

Comment: See my update. Validate you can see the chars in something other than Excel.

Comment: You're right, it works quite well in notepad++. The weird characters correspond to "...". There are still other undefined characters, represented with squares. They correspond to smileys, so it doesn't matter much for my needs ;). Thanks!