# Pyspark - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 124: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pyspark, unicode, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I get the "UnicodeEncodeError" when I try to display the spark dataframe on terminal using this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pyspark
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.exceptions import NotFoundError
### Creating Spark Session
spark = SparkSession \
                .builder \
                .appName("test") \
                .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","60s") \
                .getOrCreate() 

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

es_server_ip = "elasticsearch"
es_server_port = "9200"
es_conn = Elasticsearch("http://user:password@elasticsearch:9200",use_ssl=False,verify_certs=True)


#function to read dataframe from Elastic Search index
def readFromES(esIndex,esQuery):
    esDf = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
            .option("es.nodes",es_server_ip ) \
            .option("es.port",es_server_port) \
            .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "user") \
            .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "password") \
            .option("es.net.ssl","false") \
            .option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed","true") \
            .option("es.read.metadata", "false") \
            .option("es.mapping.date.rich", "false") \
            .option("es.query",esQuery) \
            .load(esIndex)
    return esDf

#defining the elastic search query
q_ci = """{
       "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }"""

#invoking the function and saving the data to df1
df1 = readFromES("test_delete",q_ci)
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Error:

> df1.show(truncate=False)
> File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
> 382, in show UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
> '\ufffd' in position 124: ordinal not in range(128)

I would need the output as below

```
+--------------------+------+-----+
|hostname            |kpi   |value|
+--------------------+------+-----+
|host4               |cpu   |95   |
|host3               |disk  |90   |
|Apr�ngli            |cpu   |78   |
|host2               |memory|85   |
+--------------------+------+-----+
```

You may simulate the dataframe using the below code

```
data1 = [("Apr�ngli","cpu",78),
       ("host2","memory",85),
       ("host3","disk",90),
       ("host4","cpu",95),
    ]
schema1= StructType([ \
    StructField("hostname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("kpi",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("value",IntegerType(),True)
        ])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema1)
df1.printSchema()
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Steps I took:
As mentioned in other stackoverflow answers, I did the below but still receiving the error

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

version details:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.8
Spark version 2.4.5
```

Comment: Is this in any way specific to PySpark or do you get the same exception if you do `print('\ufffd')`?

Comment: I get the same error If I do print('\ufffd') .btw, fyi - I'm submitting the code using spark-submit command.

Comment: `\ufffd` is the `�` (_Replacement Character_) in `"Apr�ngli"`. Fix it and save the script in _utf-8_ (maybe with a facultative line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`).

Comment: @JosefZ actually the character � comes from elastic search. Just for simulating here, I have created a dataframe.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @JosefZ sorry about that. my mistake. I have reframed the question

Comment: [`sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717229/3439404) and/or `.option("encoding", "utf-8")` in `spark.read`?

Comment: sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') returns error :"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding' " . Also .option("encoding", "utf-8")  didn't help