# pycharm with codecs utf-8 encode from system stdout and stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

hellow all, I'm working with python 3.6.0 on a project in pycharm community edition 2016.3.2. I have this strange error happens in my program whenever I use codecs to encode my input stream:

```
import codecs
import sys

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

print("something")
```

the problem is my program always exit with an exit code 1, and here is the console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jhonsong/Desktop/restfulAPI/findARestaurant.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("something")
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\codecs.py", line 377, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Process finished with exit code 1
```

but my input is a string, why is codecs.write think I'm giving it bytes input?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea anyway - not all consoles support UTF-8. You should print and allow Python's locale detection to work out the appropriate encoding

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack what I'm doing is trying to get this online class challenge done: [link](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud388/lessons/4628431284/concepts/52474372990923), it evolves with foursquare's API and possible multiple language results return. you are suggesting write the result to a file instead of console?

Comment: I don't have access :(

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `sys.stdout` is a Unicode stream.  `codecs.getwriter('utf8')` needs a byte stream.  `sys.stdout.buffer` is the raw byte stream, so use:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr.buffer)
```

But this seems like overkill with Python 3.6, where the `print` should just work.  Normally if you need to force an encoding, say to capture the output of a Python script to a file in a certain encoding, the following script (Windows) would work.  The environment variable dictates the output encoding and overrides whatever the terminal default is.

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
python some_script.py > output.txt
```

Since you are submitting to a website, that site should be responsible for running your script in a way that they can capture the result properly.