# Python print Unicode string via 'Git Bash' gets 'UnicodeEncodeError'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, git-bash

in **test.py** i have

```
print('Привет мир')
```

with **cmd** worked as normal

```
> python test.py
?????? ???
```

with **Git Bash** got error

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print('\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u043c\u0438\u0440')
  File "C:\Users\raksa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

[image]

Does anyone know the reason behind of getting error when execute python code via **Git Bash**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.7 you can do

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

This mostly fixes the git bash problem for me with Chinese characters. They still don't print correctly to standard out on the console, but it doesn't crash, and when redirected to a file the correct unicode characters are present.

Credit to [sth in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52372390/5729872).

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem with python 3.9

```
import sys, locale
print("encoding", sys.stdout.encoding)
print("local preferred", locale.getpreferredencoding())
print("fs encoding", sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

If this returns "cp1252" and not "utf-8" then print() doesn't work with unicode.

This was fixed by changing the windows system locale.

```
Region settings > Additional settings > Administrative > Change system locale > Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support
```

Comment: Chaing the Windows system locale was a helpful guide for running Python scripts that were pre-made by some packages. If one cannot adjust the locale in the actual code, I second the recommendation to adjust the system locale.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.6 directly uses the Windows API to write Unicode to the console, so is much better about printing non-ASCII characters.  But Git Bash isn't the standard Windows console so it falls back to previous behavior, encoding Unicode string in the terminal encoding (in your case, cp1252).  cp1252 doesn't support Cyrillic, so it fails.  This is "normal".  You'll see the same behavior in Python 3.5 and older.

In the Windows console Python 3.6 should print the actual Cyrillic characters, so what is surprising is your "?????? ???".  That is not "normal", but perhaps you don't have a font selected that supports Cyrillic.  I have a couple of Python versions installed:

```
C:\>py -3.6 --version
Python 3.6.2

C:\>py -3.6 test.py
Привет мир

C:\>py -3.3 --version
Python 3.3.5

C:\>py -3.3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print('\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u043c\u0438\u0440 \u4f60\u597d')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: So is there a way to make git bash not return an error in this situation (regardless of whether or not it prints the characters)?

Answer (score 2):

Set the the environment variable `PYTHONUTF8=1`, or
Use `-Xutf8` command line option.