# Git-bash not displaying Unicode with logging

Tags: python, unicode, git-bash, python-unicode

I am having trouble displaying Unicode characters on git-bash when working with Python's `logging`.

- Without `logging` - everything works fine.
- With `cmd` - everything works fine.
- With `PyCharm` - everything works fine.
- `logging` with `git-bash` - **not working** (displaying "\u2501").

See below...

**I am using:**

- Windows 10
- git version 2.37.2.windows.2
- Python 3.9.6 (Same issue with Python 3.7).

---

[image]

[image]

[image]
And even this not working:

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stderr.encoding)"`?

Comment: @Thomas cp1252 .

Comment: Some terminals can't print certain unicode (or any unicode in some cases). This also depends on the font being used (which can be changed). Although often a question mark symbol or similar is printed (not `\u2501`) if the glyph is missing. Try `echo $'\u2501'` in git-bash to verify if the terminal can print this character or not. Also, in my experience, unicode behaviour is fairly inconsistent across different terminals, in respect of width, alignment, and size of glyphs.

Comment: For people who want to test (and do not have OCR): `python -c "import logging; logging.error('L\u2501'); print('P\u2501')"`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Right! Good comment. Will pay attention from now on.

Comment: Side note: Git is not relevant here; git-bash is, but only in that it means you're using some kind of terminal emulation software, which in turn determines which character encoding you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as commented, `logging` is using `sys.stderr` and not `sys.stdout`.

As for the terminals (at least on my Windows machine):

- When running Python from `cmd` the default encoding for both `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` is `utf-8`.
- When running Python from `git-bash` the default encoding for both `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` is `cp1252`. Really no idea why. I would assume most `git-bash` users want Linux-like behavior.

It seems that both terminals accept `utf-8`.

Since my script only needs to be run on these two terminals, the following solves my problem:

```py
import sys
sys.stderr.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's output encoding is set to `cp1252`, which can't encode the character U+2501:

```
>>> '\u2501'.encode('cp1252')
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2501' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Normally, if you try to print this character, you would get a similar error. But since you're implicitly using [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), the default value for `errors` is `'backslashreplace'`, which explains why you're seeing backslash-escaped output instead of an error.

There are many ways to get Python to output UTF-8 instead, but don't do that: your terminal expects CP1252, so everything outside the ASCII range will be wrong.

Instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618114/14637) for a way to get Git Bash to use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: On Windows (but it will change), the default encoding of Python is not UTF-8 (it is not just for `print` but also to read files). IIRC locales are used only on Unix variants of Python

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Then why does @EladWeiss report that it works fine in `cmd`?

Comment: Maybe Python changed. In fact until few version ago python could not properly run there (there were pythonw, or other tricks). In any case, with locale with UTF-8 and git-bash, the locale is cp1252 (you can test just by using `print` instead of logging, so we have an error with the current locale).