# Python string.decode() throwing error when spawning as a child process of node.js

Tags: python, node.js, decode, child-process, spawn

I want my python script to be able to decode utf-8 encoded strings. The script works fine when called from the console and in the python interpreter. However, when I call the script as a node.js child process, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(b'\xe1\x83\x90'.decode("utf-8"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u10d0' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

My node.js file (index.js) looks like this:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const python = spawn("python", ["test.py"]);

python.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
python.stderr.pipe(process.stdout)
```

My python file (test.py) looks like this:

```
print(b'\xe1\x83\x90'.decode("utf-8"))
```

Edit:

Working code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
print(b'\xe1\x83\x90'.decode())
```

We can use `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` to check the encoding of sys.stdout.

For some reason, encoding of stdout was changed to "cp1252" (I assume by node.js?), and this line of code changes it back to "utf-8". Printing a utf-8 string when stdout was encoded with cp1252 was the problem.

Comment: This - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3 - should solve it for you. Even though the question doesn't explicitly mention it, it's the same old issue of setting up the piping for Python scripts.

Comment: Adding `import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` to the beginning of `test.py` file solved it for me.