# Every print to stdout fails because write claims its input is bytes, not string

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to debug a module, but whenever I try to print something, python 3.10 stops with the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 378, in write
self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

This error comes whatever I am trying to print, e.g. `print("abc")` or `print(type(1))`. It also occurs when calling `breakpoint()`, because breakpoint prints its messages to stdout, which does not work for some reason.

When calling `print` in a separate python shell, it works, but not when it is called from the module which is loaded in a script.

Any ideas what might case this behaviour?

Have tried to actually print the data type with `print(type(var))` and `print(isinstance(var,bytes))`, but this results in the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to convert bytes to string using appropriate encoding 'utf-8' before printing it ??

Comment: @swordfish The problem seems to be that the OP actually tried to enforce an encoding. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem typically occurs when you have tried to set the default encoding of stdout like it was done in python 2.x:

```
>>> import sys; import codecs
>>> sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)
>>> print("bla")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 377, in write
   self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
>>> print(type("bla"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 377, in write
  self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Although there are [other ways to achieve this in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3), this might lead to unintended side-effects when printing binary data that does not represent strings. It might thus be safest not to use a forced decoding method, but to explicitly call `decode` when it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = b'abc'

string_data = data.decode('utf-8')

stream.write(string_data)
```