Getting an Error when Reading CSV With Polars
I am trying to read a csv file by using Polars Library in VS Code and also trying to print it into a Data Frame. Here is the code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv("export.csv", encoding="utf8")

print(df)

I am not sure why it returned the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\Python\my_polars.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(df)
    ~~~~~^^^^
  File "C:\data\python\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 23-122: character maps to <undefined>

Has anyone had similar experience? How to solve it?

The error occurs because your terminal or environment cannot handle special characters in the CSV file due to encoding issues. If the encoding is not UTF-8, update your code to use the correct one.
Try different encoding.
df = pl.read_csv("export.csv", encoding=USE_ANOTHER_ENCODE_MODE)
Maybe you can ignore encoding errors. use encoding_errors="ignore" parameter. eg:-
df = pl.read_csv("export.csv", encoding="utf8", encoding_errors="ignore")

Thank you for this. You are right. My VS Code Built-In Output Console is unable to handle the CSV. I found the alternative by running it from DOS Terminal.

glad to hear, you welcome.

I've faced this before, because Python was assuming the default encoding was CP1252 on my Windows terminal. Changing the encoding for sys.stdout can fix the issue.

This question gives solutions to fixing the output encoding for stdout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3

The issue might be that the actual encoding of the CSV file is different from UTF-8.
Look for an encoding declaration in CSV file or use a text editor that supports encoding detection,
then update your code with the desired encoding.

The error is one the print statement, not on the statement that reads the CSV, so this is not likely to be the problem.
