# Can I redirect unicode output from the console directly into a file?

Tags: python, unicode, console

I've got a python script that outputs unicode to the console, and I'd like to redirect it to a file. Apparently, the redirect process in python involves converting the output to a string, so I get errors about inability to decode unicode characters.

So then, is there any way to perform a redirect into a file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When printing to the console, Python looks at `sys.stdout.encoding` to determine the encoding to use to encode unicode objects before printing.

When redirecting output to a file, `sys.stdout.encoding` is None, so Python2 defaults to the `ascii` encoding. (In contrast, Python3 defaults to `utf-8`.)  This often leads to an exception when printing unicode.

You can avoid the error by explicitly encoding the unicode yourself before printing:

```
print (unicode_obj.encode('utf-8'))
```

or you could redefine `sys.stdout` so all output is encoded in `utf-8`:

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout=codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
print(unicode_obj)
```

Comment: I tried encoding my string before printing it to the console. My file has b symbol and \x01 ... codepoints... When it wrote to the file, it was not decoded

Answer (score 15):

Set the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` to the encoding you want before redirecting a python script to a file.  Then you won't have to modify the original script.  Make sure to write *Unicode* strings as well, otherwise `PYTHONIOENCODING` will have no effect.  If you write byte strings, the bytes are sent as-is to the terminal (or redirected file).

Comment: Running `PYTHONENCODING=utf8 script.py` does not work for me at all. Neither PYTHONSTDENCODING which I saw purposed somewhere else. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @qwertyboy, you're doing it wrong.  Neither of those spellings are the spelling in my answer.

Comment: You are right, of course. Sorry about that, (it was a late hour) and thanks. But eventually I did try your spelling as well, here is a copy from my terminal: `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 ./quote.py > log.txt`, and it didn't work. The file command outputs `log.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text`

Comment: @qwertyboy, I don't have a Linux system handy, but is `quote.py` printing Unicode strings?  That's all it will affect.  If it is printing byte strings they dump their bytes to the display untranslated. Another possibility is your terminal isn't configured to decode UTF-8 and a simple `cat log.txt` won't display correctly.

Comment: the confusing bit is precisely that when I run quote.py on its own it displays unicode strings on my terminal perfectly. Only when I redirect it into a file does it revert to latin1, and I find myself resorting to `./quote.py | iconv -c -t utf8 > log.txt`. Explicitly marking the strings as unicode (u'string') seems to help, though, when combined with PYTHONIOENCODING. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Under Linux, you can use tee and redirect stderr to /dev/null.

```
python script.py 2>/dev/null | tee filename.txt
```

You also don't need to modify your Python script.

Answer (score 3):

```
import codecs
file_object = codecs.open( "filename", "w", "utf-8" )
file_object.write(u"खऔणन")
file_object.close()
```

This should do the job.

Comment: wah wah wah additional modification wah wah wah... accepted out of necessity.

Comment: that's barely any modification

Comment: It's a fundamental modification, as it *forces* you to write to a file, preventing using the script with a *shell* redirection.