# How to redirect utf-8 output into txt file

Tags: python, shell, utf-8, stdout, nohup

I ran a python script to write my log files using:

```
nohup python my_script.py >> log.txt
```

However, I thought maybe it is `>>` in Linux which doesn't support the Chinese characters encoded in `utf-8`.

[image]

In my script I used `print` to show the `utf-8` characters and it works well in the python shell. So I want to know how can I write the `utf-8` characters to log files correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What is the file's encoding? show it use the command : set fileencoding

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530708/can-i-redirect-unicode-output-from-the-consol-directly-into-a-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016236/python-unicode-handling-differences-between-print-and-sys-stdout-write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution. Just add one line in head of the python script:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

For example, a simple script named utf8.py:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = u'中文'
    print s.encode('utf-8')
```

Then redirect the `print` to a txt file:

```
[zfz@server tmp]$ python utf8.py >> utf8.txt
[zfz@server tmp]$ cat utf8.txt 
中文
```

The Chinese characters can be output to the txt file correctly.