# ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position error in Ubuntu/Python, but not on OS X/Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, operating-system

I'm now on Ubuntu 13.04 and Python 2.7.4 and tried to run a script including the following lines:

```
html = unicode(html, 'cp932').encode('utf-8')
html1, html2 = html.split(some_text) # this line spits out the error
```

However, when I ran the above script on Ubuntu 13.04, it spitted out an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 106: ordinal not in range(128)`. However, this exactly same script can always be executed successfully on OS X 10.8 and Python 2.7.3. So I wonder why the error occurred only one of the two platforms...

The first thought came to my mind, especially after reading this post ([UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1)) was that the dichotomy arose because I'm in a different `LANG` environment, where I use `jp_JP.UTF-8` on OS X but `en_US.UTF-8` on Ubuntu. So I also tried to add one more line `os.environ['LANG'] = 'jp_JP.UTF-8'` to the aforementioned scrip, but still got the same error.

One more strange phenomenon is that when I attempt to run the script from within IPython shell on Ubuntu and go into debug mode immediately after the error happens, and then run the line which originally triggered the error, I don't get the error any more...

So what's happening here? And what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in `some_text`? My guess is that it's a `unicode` object, not a `str`. If so, that line will effectively call `unicode(html).split(some_text)`, and that implicit conversion is where it will fail. Can you log the type and the bytes on each platform and see?

Comment: Also, the question you linked to has nothing to do with your problem. As the accepted answer says, that user's problem isn't about the encoding and decoding in his code, but about the implicit encoding that happens when he `print`s to the terminal. You're not doing that anywhere (or at least not on this line), so it won't affect you. (And, even if it did, both of your locales are using UTF-8 anyway, so that wouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: PS, why are you using `unicode(html, 'cp932').encode('utf-8')`? It's not illegal to mix and match the two different ways of converting, but it's definitely weird. Why not `html.decode('cp932').encode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to be sure, but there's a pretty good chance this is your problem:

If `some_text` is a `unicode` object, then this line:

```
html1, html2 = html.split(some_text) # this line spits out the error
```

… is calling `split` on a `str`, and passing a `unicode` parameter. Whenever you mix `str` and `unicode` in the same call, Python 2.x handles that by automatically calling `unicode` on the `str`. So, that's equivalent to:

```
html1, html2 = unicode(html).split(some_text) # this line spits out the error
```

… which is equivalent to:

```
html1, html2 = html.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).split(some_text) # this line spits out the error
```

… which will fail if there are any non-ASCII characters in `html`, exactly as you're seeing.

---

The easy workaround is to explicitly encode `some_text` to UTF-8:

```
html1, html2 = html.split(some_text.encode('utf-8'))
```

But personally, I wouldn't even try to work with `str` objects from 3 different charsets all in the same program. Why not just `decode`/`encode` at the very edges, and just deal with `unicode` objects everywhere in between?

Comment: As you mentioned, I confirmed that `html` was `str` and `some_text` was `unicode` object. After I read your comment, especially `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, I found that the reason that OS X and Ubuntu works differently is because I put `sitecustomize.py` on which I set default encoding to utf-8 on OS X but not on Ubuntu. And I put the same file also on Ubuntu, then the script ran successfully. For your information `html` was produced by urllib2.urlopen().read(), I didn't know it returns a `str` type. Thanks a lot. Really appreciated.

Comment: @user2360798: Most things in Python 2.x return a `str` if they don't say otherwise. But even in 3.x, where most things return Unicode objects, `urlopen` still returns bytes, because otherwise it would have to guess at the encoding. The resources you download aren't any more likely to use your default encoding than anything else, and considering all the ways encoding can be specified (HTTP headers, HTML head section, not at all, …) there's really no way it can guess, so it leaves it up to you.