# Using pip and easy_install: anyway “UnicodeDecodeError”

Tags: python, unicode, pip, easy-install

I am using Python 2.7 + Windows.

I wanted to install python-docx so I followed the instruction and did:

```
pip install python-docx
```

it failed so I did:

```
easy_install python-docx
```

both of them give error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

then according to searched results, I did:

```
pip install –-upgrade setuptools
```

and

```
pip install –U pip
```

all produced the same error ("UnicodeDecodeError").

How can I find what went wrong, and how can I correct it?

Comment: it worked for me on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see hugleecool's answer to the question ['ascii' codec can't decode error when use pip to install uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931726/ascii-codec-cant-decode-error-when-use-pip-to-install-uwsgi)

to add some lines above to the

```
'default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()'
```

in file

```
'C:\Python27\Lib\ mimetypes.py'
```

the lines are:

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')
    default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is" *-* "this one.ASCII has very limited characters so cant decode that smybol.First open command line.Write:

> chcp

It will return something like:

> Active code page: 857

Then write;

```
chcp 1254
```

And try your easy-install methods.It must be work.It will change your encoding and can decode much characters than before.

> Also for every case, right click on command line
>   title-->preferences/options-->font type--> Choose "Lucida Console" and
>   save it.
>
> Unfortunately Python 2x has too much problems with decode.Switch to 3x, an advice :-)