# TideSDK error while compiling (python)

Tags: macos, tidesdk

I'm trying to compile a application with TideSDK Developer, after a complete reinstallation of OSX (10.10.5) with no backups, I had to reinstall all applications, so I downloaded the latest available version of TideSDK Developer (1.4.2) and download the SDK that I've always use on this application (1.1.0).

But every time that I compile, I'm getting this error:

```
Preparing to package and launch desktop app. One moment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/tibuild.py", line 112, in
app.stage(path.join(options.destination, app.name), bundle=bundle)
File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
Done launching!
```

After moving the project folder to Application Support/TideSDK, installing the Python 3.5 and set this permissions for both Python versions:

```
export LANG="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=C

export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

Now, this is the output log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/tibuild.py", line 112, in
app.stage(path.join(options.destination, app.name), bundle=bundle)
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/osx_app.py", line 16, in stage
App.stage(self, stage_dir, bundle=bundle)
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/app.py", line 161, in stage
effess.copy_to_dir(installer_source, contents, exclude=self.env.get_excludes() + ['.dll', '.msm'])
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/effess.py", line 57, in copy_to_dir
copy_to_dir_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/effess.py", line 109, in copy_to_dir_impl
copy_item(src, dest)
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/effess.py", line 87, in copy_item
copy_items(src, dest)
File "/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.1.0/effess.py", line 100, in copy_items
for item in os.listdir(src):
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Application Support/Titanium/sdk/osx/1.1.0/installer'
Done launching!
```

Comment: I've copied the project to TideSDK folder and now I'm getting this:

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Application Support/Titanium/sdk/osx/1.1.0/installer'
Done launching!

Comment: After installing the Titanium SDK 1.1.0, getting this: `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/ricardo/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/myapp.proj/dist/osx/myapp.app/Contents/installer'
Done launching!`

Comment: Please be aware that TideSDK has nothing to do with Appcelerator or Titanium. I've removed those tags.

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran into the issue described here:
[UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1)

Try running this in the terminal before running your compilation:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you're running this compilation via another program (Titanium?), then you may have to edit your .bash_profile (in your home folder) and include the "export" line. Run this in a terminal

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the export to the end of the file.
You may have to logout and login again for this change to take effect in your installer.

P.S.: I'm in a Windows machine right now, so I can't test this yet.

Comment: Thanks Saraiva, this is TideSDK, a program to create an .dmg file with the app developed in Titanium Desktop (deprecated) :/

So I have to run this on Mac's Terminal right?

Comment: Yes. Either use nano to edit the file in Terminal, or open .bash_profile in TextEdit (or enter "open .bash_profile" in Terminal), and add that export line to the end of the file.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've installed the 2.7 python version. I will try with 3.5

Comment: export LANG="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_EN.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=C

export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

Comment: Donwloading Titanium SDK 1.1.0 from: http://api.appcelerator.net/p/v2/release-list?name=mobilesdk&guid=9f5c585e-b9e6-40b4-8ae9-c9d75cf32884