# Removing hexadecimal characters from a unicode object

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to remove the hexadecimal characters `\xef\xbb\xbf` from my string however I am getting the following error.

Not quite sure how to resolve this.

```
>>> x = u'\xef\xbb\xbfHello'
>>> x
u'\xef\xbb\xbfHello'
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print x
ï»¿Hello
>>> print x.replace('\xef\xbb\xbf', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the unicode object, otherwise Python2 will to attempt to encode `x` with the ascii codec to search for the a `str` in it.

```
>>> x = u'\xef\xbb\xbfHello'
>>> x
u'\xef\xbb\xbfHello'
>>> print(x.replace(u'\xef\xbb\xbf',u''))
Hello
```

This only holds for Python2.
In Python3 both versions will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use either the `decode` or `unicode` functions, like so:

```
x.decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
unicode(string, 'utf-8')
```

Source: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1)

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was that your Unicode string was incorrectly decoded in the first place.  Those characters are a UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM) character mis-decoded as (likely) latin-1 or cp1252.

Ideally, fix how they were decoded, but you can reverse the error by re-encoding as latin1 and decoding correctly:

```
>>> x = u'\xef\xbb\xbfHello'
>>> x.encode('latin1').decode('utf8') # decode correctly, U+FEFF is a BOM.
u'\ufeffHello'
>>> x.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8-sig') # decode and handle BOM.
u'Hello'
```