# corpus utf-8 encoding using python

Tags: python

I already use **movie_reviews** corpus to make sentiment analysis.  I replaced the existing text files with Arabic language text files, but I couldn't read and print them; I have a problem at encoding.

My code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

documents = []

for category in movie_reviews.categories():
    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category):
        documents.append([movie_reviews.words(fileid),category])   

print(documents[0])
```

I have this error:

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621799/python-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-0)

Comment: i can solve the problem with one text file by determine the path and change encoding to utf  , but i couldn't with corpus , could u give me suggestions!!!

Comment: This is an NLTK thing? Can you post the full stack trace? That looks like a Microsoft byte-order mark (BOM) which suggests that its a problem where a file is opened.

Comment: yes i import movie_reviews as corpus from nltk

Comment: NO Answers :((((((