# dill.load unicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I try to `dill.load()` some large pickle file that will cause momery error if I use `_pickle.load()`. However, I got this error

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1

What should I do?

Comment: You need to show some code. Has the pickle file been created with Python 2.7 and now you are reading it with Python 3.x?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1?rq=1