# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 118374: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am experimenting with some NLP algorithms and I am focusing now on sentiment analysis. For this reason, I downloaded from http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdredze/datasets/sentiment/index2.html some `.review` format files with positive and negative reviews.

I am using `BeautifulSoup` for parsing these XML files and for now I am only trying to read them by executing the following source code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

positive_reviews = BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/positive.review').read())
positive_reviews = positive_reviews.findAll('review_text')

negative_reviews = BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/negative.review').read())
negative_reviews = negative_reviews.findAll('review_text')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 118374: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when

```
positive_reviews = BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/positive.review').read())
```

is to be executed.

How can I fix this error?

I have also replaced

```
BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/positive.review').read())
```

with

```
BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/positive.review').read().decode('utf-8'))
```

but I am getting exactly the same error.

Finally, I have already read some relevant posts on StackOverflow but so far nothing worked for me. For example, at my terminal `echo $LANG` outputs `en_GB.UTF-8`  as it is described at the first answer of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1) but I am still getting the error above.

Comment: Did you try `BeautifulSoup(open('*******/electronics/negative.review').read().decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have tried it. I am going to add this to my post.

Comment: Your `IDE/OS` is  ascii but you need an UTF-8 **OUTPUT**. Go to system tab (on OS) and set default encoding to `UTF-8`(before `x.decode("utf-8")`). I/O (Input/Output) always use system encoding (actualy no encoding , only ascii (mean `unsigned char *`)).   Like this : `s = u"test" `, `v = "test"` and `s == v` is `True` But `Size s` = 68 and `Size v` = 41 so **bye bye byte position !**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, your comment is a bit too dense. For example, how more specifically shall I do this "Go to system tab (on OS) and set default encoding to UTF-8..."?

Comment: try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at beginning of your program

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No this did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, try replacing

```
open('*******/electronics/positive.review')
```

with

```
open('*******/electronics/positive.review', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks. I had missed that. :)