# Why is redirection not working with python scripts?

Tags: python, bash, shell, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

The following runs in the python shell (2.7.3) as expected

```
for i in range(999):
    print i, unichr(i)
```

saving it in a file (asd.py), and running in the shell

```
$ ./asd.py
```

works also, but

```
$ ./asd.py > asd.txt
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./asd.py", line 3, in <module>
    print i, unichr(i)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is that? How to work around it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python

Comment: @sr2222: that answers it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(999):
   print i, unichr(i).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: mmm? what's the difference?

Comment: @glglgl difference is .encode('utf-8')

Comment: it worked, but opening the file in gedit, it says: The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document., why is that ?

Comment: "$ iconv -f utf-8  asd.txt" try this  command

Comment: @Ammar Sorry, I was blind. Didn't see it...

Comment: same result, since my locale is "LANG=en_US.UTF-8", why was that needed ?, maybe a bug in gedit ?

Comment: @user1358: My guess is it's because there are non-printable characters in the first 999, and a text editor reasonably thinks you don't actually want to edit them.