# Process japanese with python 3 on windows 10

Tags: python, encoding

So I get a japanese input through a tkinter Entry and I want to display it in the windows console as search term and then add it to a url from which I retrieve the sourecode with the requests module.

I solved parsing the link with

`urllib.parse.quote("japanese part", encoding="utf-8")`

but using

`os.popen("chcp 65001")`

doesn't work to print japanese to the console, I still get

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16347110/4041795) answer and the corresponding question? Seems the same? Also check the other answers to that question, as there are multiple approaches.

Comment: Also, you could try adding a shebang like so `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your python script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that.
Due to german comments for myself I always use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
And yes I tried what they wrote in that answer, but nothing changed sadly.