# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2247: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

When I run my code (Python 3) I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "country.py", line 16, in <module>
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "C:\Users\benny\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 112, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "C:\Users\benny\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2247: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346914/python-3-2-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2013-i) but none work.

The code only prints one line if I fix the encoding problem by adding encoding='UTF-8. If I leave the encoding problem in place it prints almost 700 rows before it throws an error. Either way, it still won't work.

```
import csv
import country_converter as coco

with open('Interpol.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('Interpol_Extra.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:

    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    fieldnames = ['Case Happened - UN Region', 'Case Happened - Continent', 
    'Recovered - UN Region', 'Recovered - Continent'] + csv_reader.fieldnames

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for row in csv_reader:
        case_country_name = row['Case happened - Country']
        recovered_country_name = row['Recovered - Country']

        if case_country_name:
            row['Case Happened - UN Region'] = coco.convert(names=case_country_name, to='UNregion')
            row['Case Happened - Continent'] = coco.convert(names=case_country_name, to='Continent')

        if recovered_country_name:
            row['Recovered - UN Region'] = coco.convert(names=recovered_country_name, to='UNregion')
            row['Recovered - Continent'] = coco.convert(names=recovered_country_name, to='Continent')

    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233174/6619424

Comment: @Arun as described in the question, I have tried adding encoding="utf8" which was advised in another answer. It does not work.

Comment: @Arun It only outputs one row if I fix the encoding problem. If I leave the encoding problem in place it will output about 700 rows (but still not enough).

Comment: Did you identify the encoding of csv file?

Comment: @Arun yes it was UTF-8

Comment: Try this: ```import codecs;
    with codecs.open('Interpol.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csv_file:```

Comment: There are 2 ways to pass this kind of problem: the *ignore* suggested by @Arun (which IMHO is just a workaround), or the identification of the offending string. The latter requires that you show the line where the error occurs in a normal format and in hexadecimal to allow readers to make sure of the actual encoding.

Comment: @Arun I am trying this `import codecs; with codecs.open('Interpol.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csv_file, codecs.open('Interpol_Extra.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:` but it's giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta does the code in my question help identify the offending string? That's all the info I am getting. And how do I fix it?

Comment: @Arun Have also tried putting that codec onto both reader and writer like this `import codecs; codecs.open('Interpol.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csv_file, codecs.open('Interpol_Extra.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as new_file:` but it has the problem of only outputting one row.

Comment: @Arun it was a problem with my code that I just fixed! Your help identifying the encoding was great though, so thanks.

Comment: @bennygill: Glad to hear that. Please post your answer so it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used which finally worked.

As suggested by Arun in the comments, if you're having a similar problem you should read all the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character/9233174). It has the most succinct and helpful info on stack exchange for this problem.

And then re-check your code to make sure it is valid. In my case, it was some wrong indentation that finally fixed it.

```
import csv
import country_converter as coco

with open('Interpol.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file, open('Interpol_Extra.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as new_file:

    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    fieldnames = ['Case Happened - UN Region', 'Case Happened - Continent', 
    'Recovered - UN Region', 'Recovered - Continent'] + csv_reader.fieldnames

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for row in csv_reader:
        case_country_name = row['Case happened - Country']
        recovered_country_name = row['Recovered - Country']

        if case_country_name:
            row['Case Happened - UN Region'] = coco.convert(names=case_country_name, to='UNregion')
            row['Case Happened - Continent'] = coco.convert(names=case_country_name, to='Continent')

        if recovered_country_name:
            row['Recovered - UN Region'] = coco.convert(names=recovered_country_name, to='UNregion')
            row['Recovered - Continent'] = coco.convert(names=recovered_country_name, to='Continent')

        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```