# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010c' in position 0: character maps to <undefined> MariaDB and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb, decode, encode

I am trying to insert data into a MariaDB database using SQLAlchemy. I am parsing an XML file to get the data I need to insert. I have no problem reading the data. Many of the questions asked regarding this error, such as this [python 3.2 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 9629: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346914/python-3-2-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2013-i) refers to reading data from a file. However, I am getting the error at this step,

```
con_string = db_driver + '://' + db_user + ':' + db_password + '@' + db_host + ':' + db_port + '/' + db_name
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con_string, pool_pre_ping=True)

meta_data = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
table = sqlalchemy.Table('table', meta_data, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
table.insert().execute(data)
```

`data` is a dictionary. It contains the values obtained from parsing the XML file mapped to the columns of the table.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. The code you've given us raises a `NameError`.

Comment: Is data an object? Did you possibly mean `table.insert().values(data)`?

Comment: `data` is a dictionary here. Apologies, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I have also tried `stmt = table.insert().values(data)
engine.execute(stmt)` without any luck.

Comment: What charset/collation does the table use?

Comment: I have been using `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Your [mcve] should contain code snippet where you get `data` (incl. all `import`s).

Comment: Does your connection URL end with `?charset=utf8mb4` like the example shown [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection)?

Comment: @GordThompson That solved my issue! I have updated my question with how I created my `engine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to support the full range of Unicode characters we need to add  `?charset=utf8mb4` to the end of our connection URL as described at

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#charset-selection

e.g.,

```py
e = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8mb4")
```