# Understanding Python Unicode and Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, unicode, cjk

I have a Python script that writes some strings with UTF-8 encoding. In my script I am using mainly the `str()` function to cast to string. It looks like that:

```
mystring="this is unicode string:"+japanesevalues[1] 
#japanesevalues is a list of unicode values, I am sure it is unicode
print mystring
```

I don't use the Python terminal, just the standard Linux Red Hat x86_64 terminal. I set the terminal to output utf8 chars.

If I execute this:

```
#python myscript.py
this is unicode string: カラダーズ ソフィー
```

But if I do that:

```
#python myscript.py > output
```

I got the typical error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 253-254: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is that?

Comment: In your question,you said that "some strings with UTF-8 encoding" how can you make sure that the strings were encoded with UTF-8, what have you done?

Comment: @venus.w I'm sorry I can't help you much. I'm reading the strings from both a DB and CSV that are encoded in UTF-8, but I just assume that the encoding is indeed UTF-8 (since if I print out I can properly read japanese characters), but they might be actually encoded in some other character set that also allows japanese characters. I believe there are python functions that can tell you the encoding of a string and even change it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The terminal has a character set, and Python knows what that character set is, so it will automatically decode your Unicode strings to the byte-encoding that the terminal uses, in your case UTF-8.

But when you redirect, you are no longer using the terminal. You are now just using a Unix pipe. That Unix pipe doesn't have a charset, and Python has no way of knowing which encoding you now want, so it will fall back to a default character set. 
You have marked your question with "Python-3.x" but your `print` syntax is Python 2, so I suspect you are actually using Python 2. And then your `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is generally `'ascii'`, and in your case it's definitely so. And of course, you can not encode Japanese characters as ASCII, so you get an error.

Your best bet when using Python 2 is to encode the string with UTF-8 before printing it. Then redirection will work, and the resulting file with be UTF-8. That means it will not work if your terminal is something else, though, but you can get the terminal encoding from `sys.stdout.encoding` and use that (it will be None when redirecting under Python 2).

In Python 3, your code should work as is, except that you need to change `print mystring` to `print(mystring)`.

Comment: yes it is python 2, I just check, sorry for that. And you are right, if I do: print mystring.encode('utf-8') then I have no problem to redirect. Thanks for the accurate explanation.

Comment: You can force Python to use a different encoding when using pipes with the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) as well.

Comment: you said 'decode the string with utf-8 before printing it' but it should be 'encode the unicode to a utf8 encoded str before printing it' (mystring.encode('utf-8')).

Comment: Python has a way of knowing the encoding on Linux e.g., `locale.getpreferredencoding(True)`

Comment: Lennart's answer set me on the right track to find the best solution for me:
import sys
sys.stdout.write(mystring.encode('utf-8'))
instead of print. It works for both cases and I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/492711/838494

Answer (score 2):

If it outputs to the terminal then Python can examine the value of `$LANG` to pick a charset. All bets are off if you redirect.