# python... encoding issue when using linux >

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

simple test program of an encoding issue:

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"Råbjerg"      # >>> unicodedata.name(u"å") = 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE'
```

here is what i get when i use it from a debian command box, i do not understand why using redirect here broke the thing, as i can see it correctly when using without.

can someone help to understand what i have missed? and what should the right way to print this characters so that they are ok everywhere?

```
$ python testu.py
Råbjerg

$ python testu.py > A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testu.py", line 3, in <module>
    print u"Råbjerg"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

using debian  Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.7 (squeeze) configured with:

```
$ locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

EDIT: from other similar questions seen later from the pointing done below

```
#!/bin/env python1
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, locale
s = u"Råbjerg"      # >>> unicodedata.name(u"å") = 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE'
if sys.stdout.encoding is None: # if it is a pipe, seems python2 return None
    s = s.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
print s
```

Comment: ok, thanks and sorry, it is effectively like the post you pointed, and the explication is interesting over there. Just for any reference using `import locale, sys ; print sys.stdout.encoding, locale.getpreferredencoding()` can help to understand the pipe behaviour tty encoding vs None that can default to `ascii` when redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When redirecting the output, `sys.stdout` is not connected to a terminal and Python cannot determine the output encoding. When *not* directing the output, Python can detect that `sys.stdout` is a TTY and will use the codec configured for that TTY when printing unicode.

Set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to tell Python what encoding to use in such cases, or encode explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Use: `print u"Råbjerg".encode('utf-8')`

Similar question was asked today : [Understanding Python Unicode and Linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419126/understanding-python-unicode-and-linux-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to output it already encoded:

```
print u"Råbjerg".encode('utf-8')
```

This will write the correct bytes of the string in utf-8 and you'll be able to see in almost every editor/console which support `utf-8`