# Python can't write to a file despite printing perfectly fine

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm running up against what I assume is some strange encoding error, but it's really baffling me. Basically I'm trying to write a unicode string to a file as an image, and the string representation is printed fine.

```
ìԉｃïԁｉԁúлｔ ｃúɭｐâ ρáｎｃéｔｔá, ëɑ ëɭìｔ ｈａϻ ｏｆｆíｃìà ｃòлѕêɋûäｔ. Sｕｎｔ ԁëｓëｒúлｔ
```

but any way I try to write the string out to any relevant place I get the standard ascii encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters 0-3: ordinal not in range 128
```

I've tried setting the encoding of my source files, and ensuring that my system variable isn't set to ascii, and I've tried directly outputting to a file via:

```
python script.py > output.jpg
```

and none of it seems to have any effect. I feel a little silly for not being able to solve a simple encoding issue, but I've really got no clue as to where the `ascii` codec is even coming from at this point.

Relevant code:

```
def random_image(**kwargs):
    image_array = numpy.random.rand(kwargs["dims"][0], kwargs["dims"][1], 3)*255
    image = Image.fromarray(image_array.astype('uint8')).convert('RGBA')
    format = kwargs.get("format", "JPEG")
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    image.save(output, format=format)
    content = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    content = [str(ord(char)) for char in content]
    return content
```

Comment: Please include your code and full traceback. Is this a Unicode value or a byte string?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's just the thing, this is in fact the full traceback. It points literally nowhere other than the print statement that works perfectly on its own.

Comment: But that is interesting and helpful information to us anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python... encoding issue when using linux >](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430168/python-encoding-issue-when-using-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is why do you store the contents of your image in the form of a Unicode string? Images typically contain arbitrary octets and should be represented with `str` (`bytes` in Python 3), not with the `unicode` type.

When you print a Unicode string to the screen, encoding is chosen based on the environment settings. When you print it to the file, you need to specify an encoding, otherwise `ascii` is assumed. To have your program default to something more sane for files, start it with:

```
encoding = sys.stdout.encoding or 'utf-8'
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(encoding)(sys.stdout, errors='replace')
```

Comment: hmm... it writes now, but not correctly, should I use base64 instead?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, just had to remove the BOM, as for the unicode string thing, it's pretty silly, but it's interacting with some other developer's idea of what ideal is so I've got little choice in the matter.

Comment: Also bytes is totally available in Python 2.

Comment: `bytes` and `str` are one and the same in Python 2.