# Looks like logs are crashing my Django app

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku, printing

I have a Django app running on heroku.
The app keeps crashing with the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/honcho", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('honcho==0.4.2', 'console_scripts', 'honcho')()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/honcho/command.py", line 292, in main
    app.parse()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/honcho/command.py", line 129, in parse
    options.func(self, options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/honcho/command.py", line 190, in start
    sys.exit(process_manager.loop())
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/honcho/process.py", line 114, in loop
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/honcho/printer.py", line 22, in write
Process exited with status 1
```

From Honcho's [printer.py](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho/blob/master/honcho/printer.py) source code it looks like someting is going wrong while honcho is trying to write to the console.

My app is pulling data from web pages so I may print some text with accented characters. Is that related ?

Currently i'm printing things like this:

```
logger.info('Saved article' + str(title) + '.')
```

I may also dump some json from time to time:

```
logger.debug('Article: %s' % json.dumps(article_datas, indent=4))
```

It is working fine on my development machine but not on Heroku. 
Do I need to log things differently ? Why is this not working on Heroku ?

Comment: could be any writing permission on heroku ?

Comment: Other logs are working properly, I can see them without issue. I'm not sure it is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that my Heroku app needed the `PYTHONIOENCODING` evironment variable to be set to `utf-8`.

```
heroku config:set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python/4027726#4027726) question for details about `stdout` encoding.