# Linux shell: Base64 Decode with removing line breaks

Tags: python, shell, perl, awk

I have a file where each line is a base64-encoded XML document. The decoded XML documents may contain new line characters. I would like to grep out each XML document containing a given word.

The problem is that, when I decode the lines of the file, I have multiple lines for each base64-encoded line and I cannot grep it any more. I need something like `base64 decode + remove line breaks` in one step.

How can I achieve that in the Linux shell? I have Python, Perl and awk available.

```
>cat fileContainingBase64EncodedXMLsInEachLine.txt | what should I write here?
```

#### Input:

```
PGZvbz4NCjxiYXIvPg0KPC9mb28+
PGZvbz4NCjxodWh1Lz4NCjwvZm9vPg==
PGZvbz4NCjxiYXJvbWV0ZXIvPg0KPC9mb28+
```

#### Expected Output

Let's say I want the XML documents containing 'bar'

```
<foo>
<bar/>
</foo>
<foo>
<barometer/>
</foo>
```

#### An example for my problem

```
>cat fileContainingBase64EncodedXMLsInEachLine.txt | base64 --decode | grep bar
```

Delivers:

```
<bar/>
<barometer/>
```

So I do not have the full xml documents containing `bar` and `barometer`.

Comment: Your description is not clear. Add more samples of input and output in your post and do let us know your efforts too on it too.

Comment: I hopefully made it clear now. Please give feedback if not. Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you from searching a multi-line string?

Comment: @Borodin I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Gábor: I don't understand why you think the embedded newlines prevent you from searching for the keyword you're looking for. Can you please show the code that you've written to decode the base64 data?

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't try doing this directly in the shell. It's possible to parse files line by line with Bash, but it's not very efficient. You'd be better off writing a small script in Python, awk, or perl. Show us some code, with a few lines of actual input & output, explain what it's doing wrong, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I added an example what I tried

Comment: @PM2Ring yep. Each 3 lines are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some Python code that accepts a filename followed by the search word on the commandline. As usual, if either arg contains spaces, it must be quoted.

```
import sys
from base64 import b64decode

fname, pattern = sys.argv[1:]
with open(fname) as f:
    for row in f:
        row = b64decode(row).decode()
        if pattern in row:
            print(row, end='\n\n')
```

Running this on your data with "bar" as the pattern arg gives:

```
<foo>
<bar/>
</foo>

<foo>
<barometer/>
</foo>
```

---

In order to practice my rather rusty awk skills, I decided to write an awk command line to do this. It uses the standard `base64` command to do the decoding.

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="base64 -d"}; {print |& cmd; close(cmd,"to"); z=""; while(cmd |& getline s) z=z s "\n"; close(cmd); if (z~pat)print z}' pat='bar' testdata_b64.txt
```

You pass it the pattern using the `pat` argument, which can be a regex. You can send data to it via standard input, or you can give it one or more filenames on the commandline.

Note that regex patterns need double escaping, eg `pat='\\<bar\\>'` matches the word `bar`.

Comment: definitely much better then my answer below.

Comment: @ZaphoOxx +1 for self critic :)

Comment: Question: how would it look like, if it would work with standard input?

Comment: @GáborLipták Yes, you can hard-code `sys.stdin` as the filename, if you like. However, on Linux, you can use `/dev/stdin` to pass stdin as a filename.

Comment: I'm curious to know how the awk version compares in speed to my python version. awk is faster at simple text processing, but there's some overhead in that pipeline to the `base64` command.

Comment: @PM2Ring after processing some big files I had to realize, that awk is too slow. I needed to make some changes to the script to set output encoding, otherwise I could not redirect the output into a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146524/337621

Comment: @GáborLipták I see. You didn't mention encoding issues in your question, so I didn't worry about it in my answer. I've set UTF-8 as the encoding in my terminal (konsole), so my Python code normally does what I want. But maybe for your use case you should be writing to a named file instead of using redirection. You can pass an `encoding` keyword arg to `open` to ensure a specific encoding.

Comment: @PM2Ring no problem. This is something unusual for me, that a software behaves different if I redirect its output. I am not used to it. I have to learn more python :)

Answer (score 1):

**update:** if you know that the first node name is `<foo>`, then you can just do :

```
$ echo "<head>$(base -decode <file>)</head>" | \
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//bar/ancestor::foo' -c .
```

It selects the ancestor named `foo` of the node called `bar`, since `foo` is the first xml-node, it will select the requested xml file.

**original answer below:**

Using `xmlstarlet` you might want to do this

```
$ echo "<head>$(base -decode <file>)</head>" | \
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//bar/ancestor::*[last()-1]' -c .
```

This essentially selects the full xml-tree of ancestors of the node 'bar' but it will only go upto the correct depth.

I added an extra `head` node to make the full string a valid `xml` file. This way you only need to print from the first node onwards.

The `echo` would produce something like (slightly different version):

```
<head> 
  <foo /> 
  <foo> 
    <barometer /> 
  </foo> 
  <foo> 
    <DDD> 
      <BBB/> 
      <bar /> 
    </DDD> 
  </foo> 
</head>
```

`xmlstarlet` will do a template selection based on the xpath `//bar/ancestor::*`, leading to the following set of matches

- `<bar />`
- `<DDD><BBB /><bar /></DDD>`
- `<foo><DDD><BBB /><bar /></DDD></foo>`
- `<head> everything </ head>`

We are interested in the penultimate one, i.e. `[last()-1]` and we ask to print a copy of it `-c .`

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -nE '$_=decode_base64($_);/bar/&&say' fileContaining...txt
```

or

```
cat fileContaining...txt | perl -MMIME::Base64 -nE'$_=decode_base64($_);/bar/&&say'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following python script. It is not a commandline onliner but this should give you what you want. For usage do:

```
>python3 get_xml.py SEARCHSTRING FILENAME
```

output for you example was:

```
<foo>
<bar/>
</foo>
<foo>
<barometer/>
</foo>
```

script:

```
import base64
import sys
script_name = sys.argv[0]
search_string = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2]
print("[+] ({}) search for {}".format(script_name,search_string,filename))
with open(filename,"r") as xml_in:
    nextline = xml_in.readline()
    while nextline != '':
        xml = base64.b64decode(nextline).decode("utf-8").rstrip()
        if search_string in xml:
            print(xml)
        nextline = xml_in.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` inside a loop to remove all new lines for each of the XML documents like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line
do
    echo -n "$line" | base64 --decode | tr -d '\r\n'
    echo
done < fileContainingBase64EncodedXMLsInEachLine.txt
```

Comment: Please see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/88378). The main reason is that `read` is very CPU-intensive: it issues a system call to the kernel for _each character_ it reads.