# Output is good in CMD and vscode but not in text/json file [python][Devanagari]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, character-encoding, char, devanagari

This code executes properly and output in terminal/cmd/VScode is good [Devanagari]. but when I try
to save it like demo.py>test.json this
**'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 150-153: character maps to** 
error present in that file.

[image]

```
import requests

headers = {
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'User-Agent': 'okhttp/5.0.0-alpha.2'
    }
i = "680"
url = "https://example.com/get/demo_id?id="+str(i)

try:
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers) 
    print(response.text)
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/19145183/4046632 However why not just write/dump the response to file from within the code?

Comment: And using catch-all Exception is bad