# unicode and encoding for persian or arabic in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

some chunk of code like this:

```
city_name = obj['city_from']['name'].encode('utf-8')
            print(city_name)
```

The output from this code is:

```
b'\xd8\xa8\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb3'
```

and if i remove encode('utf-8') output change like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this output language is persian(like arabic), i wonder why the string class in python3 does not have any decode method? 
Do you have any solutions to this problem?

thanks

Comment: Your terminal expects ASCII, so Python complies. Try changing the character set your terminal uses to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey i found my solution and it is working like a charm

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(TestText2)
```

UPDATE:
this problem for ZSH script environment, i use bash and everything is find.

Comment: Since you've now proven your terminal/console is capable of showing UTF-8, see this answer to be able to use `print` without encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169209/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom: How bytes are interpreted as text is defined by *user environment*. Printing bytes that represent text "as is" as well as hardcoding the character encoding in your script is too assuming about the user environment. [Either the environment should be fixed for all programs (in any language) that may produce non-ascii output or `PYTHONIOENCODING` may be configured explicitely for the script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22552581/4279)

Answer (score 2):

[Your answer shows that your terminal accepts utf-8 byte sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543438/4279).

You don't need to convert Unicode string into bytes before printing them. Python does it for you.

To change the character encoding that Python uses for I/O; set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` environment variable or change your locale settings.

It looks like `sys.stdout.encoding` is `ascii` in your case.

```
$ python3 -c'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)' 
UTF-8
$ python3 -c'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)' | cat
ascii
$ LC_CTYPE=C python3 -c'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)' 
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

`ANSI_X3.4-1968` is a canonical name for `ascii`.

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=uTf-8 python3 -c'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)' | cat
uTf-8
$ LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 python3 -c'import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)' 
UTF-8
```

Don't hardcode the character encoding inside your scripts. Print Unicode strings and configure your environment appropriately instead

Comment: OH :|
my ZSH it is problem, when i use zsh encoding is ascii

Comment: Do you have `C.UTF-8` locale (run `locale -a`)? Try `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 python3 ...` to override other locale settings (priority: `LC_ALL` > `LC_CTYPE` > `LANG`). Note: How to change the locale permanently is system-dependent e.g., on my system there is `/etc/default/locale` file: `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`