# Unable to print some unicode characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I need to print some unicode characters in Python 2.7.

Why does the following code gave me an error?

```
print(u'\u2601')
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2601' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @Celeo You can reproduce this error via http://repl.it/languages/Python, for example

Comment: Is this of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python?

Comment: It depends on your locale; in your case, Python assumes standard output needs to be ASCII-encoded, rather than UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Normally, Python detects the console encoding.  Using `ascii` implies the locale isn't set up properly, or the output is being piped somewhere besides the console.

Comment: `repl.it` console just doesn't support Unicode. Neither does the Windows console (actually it's a more complicated story in that case, but that's the upshot for most people). https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails