# Python can't print Unicode when piped to file

Tags: python

Python correctly handles printing Unicode until you try to pipe it to a file.

Compare:

```
$ python -c "print u'\u2018'"
‘
```

To:

```
$ python -c "print u'\u2018'" > out.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode    character u'\u2018' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python

Comment: Set PYTHONIOENCODING or encode explicitly. There is no terminal to autodetect the encoding for when you redirect.

Comment: python -c "import sys; reload(sys);sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8');print u'\u2018'" > out.txt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python