# Displaying Unicode Drawing Characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have figured out how to use the characters I need but it works differently in the console on linux versus the windows console.  I want to figure out if there is a way to resolve this where I can make it work on both or at least check to see what system it is running on and call the right code.

This is using the Coding Ground terminal at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php
It uses Fedora Release 21 and Python v2.7.5.  This is my initial code:

```
# Unicode Test
print u'\u2554'
```

This gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                      
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print u'\u2554'                                                                                                                                                                                                     
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2554' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On Windows 7 console using Python 2.7.9 this runs correctly and prints the '╔' character. To make it run correctly on the linux terminal I have to use

```
# Unicode Test
print u'\u2554'.encode('UTF-8')
```

Unfortunately this code will not run correctly under the Windows console. If I use `print u'\u2554'.encode('UTF-8')` on Windows I get `b'\xe2\x95\x94'`

Any ideas on how I can make it run on both systems with out having to maintain different code for each console?

Comment: I'm getting `╔` in ubuntu 14.10, Py 2.7.5

Comment: `print u'\u2554'.encode('UTF-8')` should work on both.  Why can't you use that?

Comment: @jwodder in my windows cmd shell i get the wrong thing if you encode to utf8

Comment: @jwodder if I used `print u'\u2554'.encode('UTF-8')` I get `b'\xe2\x95\x94'` printed in the console.

Comment: Your Linux console setting isn't being detected by Python. For a fix see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362647/5987

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default encoding of your terminal in linux, on terminal click right then from`Terminal` select `Set Character Encoding` then select `Unicode (UTF-8)`. for more info read http://www.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html

Comment: I know enough linux to be dangerous sitting at a terminal but I don't believe that option is available using the terminal at Coding Ground.      (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php)