# python 3.4 encoding in windows 8.1

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, windows-8.1

I use the script mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python/30939506#30939506), to check the encoding:

```
import sys, locale, os
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(sys.stdout.isatty())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print(os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"])
print(chr(246), chr(9786), chr(9787))
```

and I obtain (python 3.4, windows 8.1):

```
windows-1252
False
cp1252
mbcs
windows-1252
ö Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../UTF8-comprovacio.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(chr(246), chr(9786), chr(9787))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u263a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm trying to change windows 8.1 encoding (e.g. I add an environment variable called "PYTHONIOENCODING" vith utf8 value) but the result is always the same. How can I change the encoding and the value of PYTHONIOENCODING in Windows 8.1? (in fact, I have another computer, also with Windows 8.1, that shows the correct values, utf-8, but I don't know why)

Comment: Basic sanity check: you have tried:import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Comment: thanks, but as far as I know, reload(sys) doesn't work in python 3.4.

Comment: I'm not sure the reload is necessary but in case: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857027/youtube-api-unicodeencodeerror-in-python-3-4) last week... I ended up just changing in IDE. Don't know your IDE, but if PyCharm, starting from the menu bar: File -> Settings... -> Editor -> File Encodings, then set: "IDE Encoding", "Project Encoding" and "Default encoding for properties files" ALL to UTF-8 and she now works like a charm.

Maybe yours has a similar option.

Comment: This was actually the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help... please feel free to mark as the answer.